# How to get Mathematica to integrate over multivariate constrained ranges

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I am trying to get an answer to:

```
Integrate[Exp[k*Cos[\[Theta] ]], {\[Theta], 0, 2*Pi}]
```

which I happen to know is proportion to $\mathbb{I}_0(k)$, which is the modified Bessel function of the first kind of the zeroeth order.

I want to generalize the above to obtain the multivariate integral:
$$ \exp(a_1 y_1 + a_2 y_2 + \ldots + a_py_p)$$ over the range: $y_1^2 + y_2^2 + \ldots + y_p^2 = 1$. The above Mathematica code snippet holds for the special case that $a_i = k \forall i$ and for $p=2$. Can I put this sort of general range and integration over $p$ variables in Mathematica?

The suggested solution does not work:

```
Integrate[Exp[a1*y1+a2*y2],Element[{y1,y2},Sphere[{0,0}]]]
```

I get
[image]

Comment: Yes, indeed. oops! Thanks for pointing this out. Sorry, it is an error. It works.

Comment: `Integrate[Exp[k*Cos[θ]], {θ, 0, Pi}]`

Comment: yes, correct, sorry. And I think that I have solved my question. I don't need Mathematica. But in general, how does one put restricted ranges, like on a sphere? Thanks!

Comment: Try `Integrate[Exp[a1*y1+a2*y2],Element[{y1,y2},Sphere[{0,0}]]]`.

Comment: If you open the [documentation for Sphere](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sphere.html), the very first thing it says is that "Sphere[p], represents a unit sphere centered at the point p."

Comment: Yes, indeed, sorry. But I get no interpretation possible. But is the answer not the Bessel function $\mathbb I_0(\sqrt{a_1 + a_2)$ times some constant.

Comment: Yes it is `2 Pi BesselI[0,Sqrt[a1^2+a2^2]]`. Maybe it is because you are using an old version of Mathematica. I am in Version 12.3 and it works without problem.

Comment: thanks, i have version 12.3.1.0, let me try again. no, still the same result. "No interpretation possible."

Comment: That is exactly the version I have (I am on Linux, but probably that is irrelevant). Make sure you have a fresh kernel (`Quit[]`). Maybe you are using Wolfram Alpha or something and did not input this as regular Mathematica code. Sorry, I will not be able to help.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I quit and got back in, but same result. I do not want to reboot, this is linux after all, and why should the kernel be an issue. I am using 5.19.16-200.fc36.x86_64.

Comment: Don't start by typing an equal sign, just evaluate `Integrate[Exp[a1*y1 + a2*y2], Element[{y1, y2}, Sphere[{0, 0}]]]`

Comment: I meant restart the Mathematica kernel, not the linux kernel. Anyhow, do you see the orange equality sign on the left? It means you are not entering this as regular code, but as some free form input. Get rid of the orange equality sign and you will be fine.

Comment: Thanks! I see, i thought the orange equality sign meant the way to evaluate. I guess not. I updated to 13.1.0 (because that is what my license key says now) and it works, but because of removing the orange equality sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

`Sphere[{0, 0}]` is just a [`Circle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Circle.html)

```
Region[Sphere[{0, 0}]]
```

[image]

```
Integrate[Exp[a1*y1 + a2*y2],
 Element[{y1, y2}, Sphere[{0, 0}]]]

(* 2 π BesselI[0, Sqrt[a1^2 + a2^2]] *)

Integrate[Exp[a1*y1 + a2*y2],
 Element[{y1, y2}, Circle[{0, 0}]]]

(* 2 π BesselI[0, Sqrt[a1^2 + a2^2]] *)
```

Similarly, `Ball[{0, 0}]`  is just a [`Disk`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Disk.html)

```
Region[Ball[{0, 0}]]
```

[image]

```
Integrate[Exp[a1*y1 + a2*y2],
  Element[{y1, y2}, Ball[{0, 0}]]] //
 FunctionExpand

(* (2 π BesselI[1, Sqrt[a1^2 + a2^2]])/Sqrt[a1^2 + a2^2] *)

Integrate[Exp[a1*y1 + a2*y2],
  Element[{y1, y2}, Disk[{0, 0}]]] //
 FunctionExpand

(* (2 π BesselI[1, Sqrt[a1^2 + a2^2]])/Sqrt[a1^2 + a2^2] *)
```

Comment: One can use `With[{p=4}, Integrate[Exp[a*y[1]], Element[Array[y,p],Sphere[p]], GenerateConditions->False]]` for dimension $p$. The parameter $a$ plays the role of $\sqrt{a_1^2 + \ldots + a_p^2}$.

Comment: Can we get an evaluation for general p? I guess my question is what if the a is a p-dimensional vector and we ahve a'y?

Comment: I don't know how to get Mathematica to evaluate for a general $p$, but if you evaluate for a few small $p$, you can see that the answer is `a*(2*Pi/a)^(p/2)BesselI[p/2-1,a]` where $a = \sqrt{a_1^2 + \ldots + a_p^2}$.

Comment: Perhaps, I should ask another question for this case? I would like to know how to handle vectors (and matrices) with general p, if that is indeed, possible.

Comment: Also, btw, what does 'y[1]` in your code snippet do? Is it the first element of y?

Comment: `y[1]` is an indexed variable. Indexed variables are more convenient to work with than forms like `{y1, y2, y3}` since they readily work with `Map`, `Table`, `Do`, `For`, etc.

Comment: But I wanted the integral of `exp(sum(a[1]*y[1]+a[2]*y[2] + ... + a[p]*x[p]))` is the above by @user293787 doing the right thing?

Comment: Yes it is. The integral of $\exp(a_1y_1 + \ldots + a_py_p)$ only depends on the length $a = \sqrt{a_1^2 + \ldots + a_p^2}$, by rotation symmetry. Therefore, you get the same result if you integrate $\exp(a y_1)$ (effectively rotating the vector to point in the 1-direction). It seems to be easier for Mathematica to evaluate the latter integral.